# Одновременный вывод в консоль и в файл

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли в .NET'e способ писать поток вывода в два стрима одновременно?

То есть сделать `Console.SetOut()` и для `Console.Out` и для `StringWriter` например.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если решать задачу "в лоб", можно сделать небольшую обёртку, которая будет это делать. Например:

```
public class MultiWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly List<TextWriter> _writers;

    public MultiWriter(params TextWriter[] writers)
    {
        _writers = new List<TextWriter>(writers);
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        _writers.ForEach(_ => _.Write(value));
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var consoleWriter = Console.Out;

        // Перенаправляем вывод в наш writer и пишем в консоль тестовую строку
        Console.SetOut(new MultiWriter(stringWriter, consoleWriter));
        Console.WriteLine("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");

        // Возвращаем на место стандартный writer
        Console.SetOut(consoleWriter);

        // ...и проверяем результат
        Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Alexander, спасибо! Работает, только вместо `StringWriter` взял `StreamWriter("log2.log") { AutoFlush = true };` потому как `AutoFlush` помогает все сразу же писать в файл. За идею спасибо!

Comment: @AntonKomyshan не забудьте задиспоузить райтер, когда он станет не нужен.